# Problem with executing query in python using cursor.execute()

Tags: python, mysql

I have a `set` function followed by `;` in my query and cursor.execute thinks I'm running multiple queries and says use `multiple=true' but in fact I'm just running one query.
How can I tell python consider my whole string a single query?

```
agent_report_query = """
```

`set` @StartDate = `'2020-04-01 00:00:00'`;

`set` @EndDate = `'2020-04-02 00:00:00'`;

`SELECT`
    Date,
    Name
`FROM` tbl

`WHERE`
    user_calculated_data.date >= @StartDate
`And`
    user_calculated_data.date < @EndDate

```
"""
```

then I execute this:

```
    cursor2 = con2.cursor()
    cursor2.execute(agent_report_query)
    AgentReport = cursor2.fetchall()
    print("AgentReport Query executed successfully!")
    for i in AgentReport:
       print(i)
```

And the result is:

mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Use multi=True when executing multiple statements

if I use: `cursor2.execute(agent_report_query,multi=False)`

the result is:

mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.

**could you please help me?**

Comment: Do you need to run all three statements in one call? Why not just run them one at a time?

Comment: because they depend each other I use startdate and Enddate in my select statement.

Comment: and also when i use `cursor2.execute(agent_report_query,multi=True)` it act like what you said and execute them one call and you can see there is nothing to fetch.

Comment: If you use the same database connection, you can set variables in one `execute()` call and use them in a query in a subsequent `execute()` call. They don't have to be in the same call.

Comment: Yes this is my final soloution , because I used these two variablesh a lot of time in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has some errors

First the dates have to be in quotes

Second You SELECT startemne has a comma too much

```
set @StartDate = '2020-04-01 00:00:00';

set @EndDate = '2020-04-02 00:00:00';

SELECT Date, Name FROM tbl
WHERE user_calculated_data.date >= @StartDate And user_calculated_data.date < @EndDate;
```

What you can do also is make for every query a own exute

```
agent_report_query = """
SELECT Date, Name FROM tbl
WHERE user_calculated_data.date >= @StartDate And user_calculated_data.date < @EndDate;
"""

cursor2.execute("set @StartDate = '2020-04-01 00:00:00';")

cursor2.execute("set @EndDate = '2020-04-02 00:00:00';")

cursor2.execute(agent_report_query)
```

Or

you make thisi don't see hwy you are using user defined variables at all for this query

```
agent_report_query = """
SELECT Date, Name FROM tbl
WHERE user_calculated_data.date >= ? And user_calculated_data.date < ?;
"""
cursor2.execute(agent_report_query,("2020-04-01 00:00:00","2020-04-02 00:00:00"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your update,it was my kistake when writing the post.

Comment: I run my query successfuly in mysql workbench and there is no error.

Comment: I updated my answer see if this solves your problem